# Trigger an action when timer expires in the background

Tags: swift, timer

I’ve developed a Xcode app to trigger an action on timer expiry. This works fine when the app is visible on the device. However when the app is minimised eg. the Home button is pressed, the app doesn’t work. It seems like the app gets suspended. It resumes the countdown when it is brought to the foreground again.
Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Search for background task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timers will only run in the background if your app is running in the background for another reason. You will need to enable a background mode on the capabilities page. Your timer will also need to have already started when you enter the background

This may also be helpful:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Thank you for this. I did this software config change and it works in the Simulator as expected. However, the app does not perform the same when I download it onto my iPhone. Can you please assist with this if possible. Regards,